# Why doesn't this formula work?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Consider the following (partial) Excel sheet:

```
 | A |   B     C     D
-+---+------------------
1|id | comp1 comp2 comp3
-+---+------------------
2| 1 |   1     0     0
3| 1 |   1     0     0
4| 2 |   0     1     0
5| 3 |   0     0     1
6| 1 |   1     0     0
7| 3 |   0     0     1
```

As an example, if filled in all zero's and one's in columns `B`, `C` and `D` by hand. I need to automate this because my dataset is to large to do it all manually. I need, for instance for cell `B2`, a formula which checks whether value of `A2` is similar to company `id` in cell `B1`. If so, set a `1`, else a `0`. Another example: take row 4. It has company `id` `2` in cell `A4` so `B4` (comp1) should be `0`, `C4` `1` and `D4` `0`.

I have used the following formula in cell B2, ready to be dragged to all other cells:

```
=IF($A2=RIGHT(B$1;1);1;0)
```

However, it puts a `0` in B2. I don't understand, because `A2` has value 1, and so does `RIGHT(B1;1)`, so `IF(1=1;1;0)`, so `B2` should get value `1`. But it doesn't where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because right() returns a string and you compare a string to a number. You need to transform that string to a number, e.g. with value(right(...)).